# Javascript, Intellisense and compiler notification

Tags: javascript

Being a C# developer, I cannot grasp why in the world one would spend time designing a perfect class in javascript, when you can't get any editor today with intellisense that will fully show you your class rules. There is only one way to maintain a well designed class in JS by documenting everything, and requiring a developer that uses the class to always refer back to its documentation.

For me - trying to become a professional javascript developer - it's so frustrating, I feel so unproductive. why is that? why can't we get an editor that will work just like C#. or maybe we would be better off if browsers starts to support a normal OOP language?

Comment: A rant and closed as such. However, I'm not quite sure if you're ranting about prototype OO (if you even know what that is - you're talking about classes, so I assume not), dynamic typing, or both. Would you care to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: The concepts of OOP were invented and in common use a long time before intellisense. The lack of intellisense does not make OOP a bad idea. It may make *you* feel unproductive, but a good developer should be able to read and write code in their language without any code hinting if they needed to.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the 'capabilities' of Javascript, (I know about prototype OO) but rather about the capabilities of the IDE's, It wasn't actually a rant at all, I was hoping to get a feel what other developers thing about this subject, or if someone would enlighten me why there is no focus on making Javascript IDE with better intellisens, maybe someone could point me to an IDE that does a good job. It was just a discussion about Javascript and Intellisense. maybe the title of the question sounded like rant but it wasn't my intent.

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio** works quite well considering the fact that Javascript is a very dynamic language where certain functionality/fields can be added removed from an object at any moment. And Javascript isn't really OOP in a sense you know in C#. It's prototyped which is different.

Think of such an engine and you'll see that Visual Studio is doing quite well with its Javascript intellisense support.

### How to enable intellisense in certain file

You have to reference other javascript files in yours to get intellisense for their functionality of course...

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />
```

Paths are relative to your file. This will make it possible to get intellisense for jQuery in any of your files that will have this directive right at the top of the file. References must be used to actually *enable* particular file's intellisense. This makes sense of course since you can have multi-faceted functions defined in various files and only one of them is used per page. Each using a different one.

### Your plugins and VS JS Intellisense documentation

And when you want your code to be reused you can always add XML documentation to your code file and others will get intellisense as well while using your Javascript code file. If you don't know how to do this check the plugin on [this blog post of mine](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html) and check the `.toDictionary()` function that has the documentation that Visual Studio is able to use for intellisense purposes.

Comment: JS isn't *class-based* OOP, yes. But it's prototype-based *OOP*.

Comment: @Robert-Koritnik The purpose of this question was to produce these kind of Answers. So, please explain why you voted to close this topic

Comment: @Shrage Smilowitz: I votes this question to be closed because of its argumentative nature. It's your personal perception that Javascript intellisense is bad or even not available at all. So this is highly subjective and argumentative. And as such should be closed. but I answered it as well to give some sanity check information in this regard. As you can see others thought the same as well so it got closed pretty fast. If you still have a question regarding JS intellisense you should reformulate your question in nonsubjective way.

Answer (score 0):

The OOP design around javascript is more for creating a clean, maintainable, code base. You'll have seams you can use to write QUnit tests for.  You can easily identify errors and rewrite code without fear of breaking stuff.  You can create namespaces and closures as well.  OOP is not about code completion is more about a way to write your code and not have your code written for you ;)